# Saving Hubot Input to a Variable

Tags: javascript, nlp, hubot

All I can find in the documentation is `.hear("specific phrase")`, or similar methods of processing input. Is there a way to simply store all input to the bot as a variable? The reason for this is that I intend on filtering this input through an NLP library to allow for natural language input to the bot. Any help is appreciated.

[hubot on github](https://github.com/github/hubot).

Comment: What functionality are you looking for out of Hubot? If you just want a direct link to the chat system (instead of the message processing Hubot provides), you are probably better off using the appropriate API client. Alternatively, are you looking to leverage the chat system adapter abstraction Hubot provides? Or, finally, are you wanting to put the NLP library in between the chat system and Hubot scripts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you're asking is if you can take what the person says to hubot, and put that into a variable. I do this with the following code:

```
module.exports = function(robot) {
robot.hear(/^(.*)/, function(msg) {
var content = msg.match.input;

});
}
```

Then, you can do whatever you want with the "content" variable. If you have any further questions, I'd be happy to answer them, assuming you haven't solved your problem already.